# Replacing img src in textarea using jquery from a pop-up window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popup, textarea

I'm trying to replace the textarea and input box image source in the parent window using jquery from a pop-up window. The text in the input box changes without any trouble, however the text in the textarea box remains unchanged.

Here's the code for the parent window:

```
<textarea cols="100" rows="20" class="editor">
    <a href="http://www.amazon.com">
        <img src="image.jpg" alt="replace image source in this textbox" />
    </a>
</textarea> 

<input type="text" value="image.jpg" maxlength="255" MultiLine="false" Class="inputBox" style="width:875px;" />

<a href="/PopUpBox" class="popup">Click Here To Add An Image/s</a>

<script type = "text/javascript">
    $('.popup').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        window.open($(this).attr("href"), "popupWindow", "width=750, height=800, toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes");
    });
</script>
```

Here's the code for the pop-up window:

```
<div class="selectButton">
<input id="select" class="selectImage" type="button" data-imagepath="image2.jpg" value="Select">
</div>

<script type = "text/javascript">    
$('.selectImage').live("click", function (e) {
         var selectImage = $(this).data("imagepath");
         window.opener.$(".editor img").attr("src", selectImage); // can't change img src in textarea box
         window.opener.$(".inputBox").val(selectImage);
         self.close();
         e.preventDefault();
     });   
</script>
```

Any ideas why this isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Vikram Deshmukh is along the right lines. @Olalekan is also correct, the content of a textarea is text, it can't manipulated like HTML.

I posted the same question here to get the answer:

https://forum.jquery.com/topic/replacing-img-src-in-textarea-using-jquery-from-a-pop-up-window-25-9-2014

Here's the solution which works:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    $('.selectImage').live("click", function (e) {
        var selectImage = $(this).data("imagepath");
        window.opener.$('.editor').val(function (i, value) {
            return value.replace(/src="[^"]+"/, 'src="' + selectImage + '"');
        });
        window.opener.$(".inputBox").val(selectImage);
        self.close();
        e.preventDefault();
    });   
</script>
```

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get image source in a textarea.Textarea respond to code as text not element.

You can use div and make it contenteditable.

```
<div contenteditable="true"></div>
```

Or get the value of editor and paste it in a div, select your image from a div

```
var editor = $(".editor").val();
$(".output").html(editor);
```

jQuery live function is deprecated use "0n"

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the textarea value with the updated HTML string as shown below:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">    
$('.selectImage').live("click", function (e) {
         var selectImage = $(this).data("imagepath");
         window.opener.$(".editor img").val(
           '<a href="http://www.amazon.com">'
             + '<img src="'+selectImage+'" alt="replace image source in this textbox" />'
           +'</a>');
         window.opener.$(".inputBox").val(selectImage);
         self.close();
         e.preventDefault();
     });   
</script>
```

Comment: I'll have dynamic content coming into the text area so this solution won't be suitable.

Comment: Sorry this involves a pop-up. I don't think jsfiddle can work with pop-ups.

Answer (score 0):

In your popup window, just replace this JS code:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">    
$('.selectImage').click(function (e) {
         var selectImage = $(this).data("imagepath");
         window.opener.$(".editor img").attr("src", selectImage); // can't change img src in textarea box
         window.opener.$(".inputBox").val(selectImage);
         self.close();
         e.preventDefault();
     });   
</script>
```